# Using screen buffers to create a program to 'edit' the text displayed in console

Tags: python, console, buffer

Standard linux apps such as Nano display a pageful of text in the console, and then 'edit' (change) it in response to user events.

A standard python app using `print` can only simply print to the console.

Can I create an app simialar to Nano in that it can 'edit' text on the screen in Python.

Google tells me about screen buffers, however I don't see anything about them in Python.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not check but I'm pretty sure that, like most UNIX programs with command line user interfaces, nano uses the **curses/ncurses** library to display on terminal.

This is a quite famous and easy-to-use library, [look at its wikipedia's page if you want to know more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

As you can see from the wiki, it is available for python, and a quick search on google would give you some place to start, [like this tutorial for example](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/code-project-build-ncurses-ui-python) (did not read it, but it seems to cover the basics).

Good luck